# Unable to declare a latex environment

Tags: latex

I tried using this code

```
\newenvironment{bashcommands}{\ttfamily\color[RGB]{22,22,22}\begin{Verbatim}}{\end{Verbatim}}
```

But ended up spitting out an error. The error however was not related to this command, but related to another command that I put earlier. I have verified that command to be correct on this site.

This is the error I get in case anyone wants to look at it.

```
Runaway argument?
! File ended while scanning use of \FancyVerbGetLine.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.136 \include{chapters/chapter2}
```

Any help with solving this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is restrictions tu use of Verbatim environmnent, you should use `\CustomVerbatimEnvironment` available in the "[fancyvrb](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fancyvrb/fancyvrb.pdf)" package to define your own verbatim environments.

Comment: Any chance this would work with \colorbox as well?
colorboxes always give me trouble.

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd comment out all of your include statements and just test the usage of this environment in a simple context.  If you just keep hitting enter, or force it into quiet mode as it compiles, it will produce lots of errors, but it will give you a readable dvi or pdf (depending on your latex call).  Examining exactly what it spit out along with the log file should give you an idea of what is happening.